Next js 14 + NextAuth.js v5 on production with Nginx what should i set the AUTH_URL
what should I set the  AUTH_URL on production while I am deploying the project using  Nginx web server when i set AUTH_URL domain name the  project does run
I get error Request Header Or Cookie Too Large
while if I keep localhost:3000 the project run while but on error it redirect to localhost:3000/error
Because  the baseUrl in next auth is localhost:3000
this is nginx config
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
#proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

